# Possible solutions for partial match (at least p out of n fields matches)

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm looking for a possible solution for partial match/possible match (at least p out of n fields matches).

We have a database (Oracle) filled with person records as follows:

- firstName,
- lastName,
- birthDate,
- citizenNumber,
- citizenPlace,
- birthPlace,
- anotherNumber,
- district.

(*) Bear in mind that there is no unique identifier and not all fields can be provided, some fields could be optional (null).

We are looking for a solution to check a given person against the database records, if there is at least 5 out of 8 fields matches.

Is it possible to have a solution using SQL, SQL/Java or should we look for nosql or elastic search solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `where` and count the matches:

```
select t.*
from t
where ( (case when t.firstname = :firstname then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t.firstname = :lastname then 1 else 0 end) +
        . . .
      ) >= 5;
```

Comment: Awesome thinking!